# I am working in PWA application and I want some printing of a table directly to printer

Tags: node.js, printing, node-modules, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I am working in the PWA application and I want some printing of a table directly to the printer. My application is on Angular6 PWA and backend is node js. Can anyone help on this? I don`t want window.print() to print through the browser.

Comment: Currently using npx-printer node module in angular to print table but it will open in browser default print preview to print.